# Interprocess Communication on Heroku

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, heroku, redis, ipc

I have a Rails app that is communicating with a Python chatbot daemon over dbus. It isn't running on Heroku because Heroku doesn't have dbus installed.

A few questions

1) Should I try IPC a different way? I've read that Redis Pub/Sub could be a possible choice. Would this involve installing a different buildpack that could support both Python and Ruby dependencies? (Since I would need to install the Redis client on both ends)

2) How would I install dbus if I were to do it on Heroku? Normally the instructions are to run apt-get install dbus-1, but I can't do that on Heroku...

Answer (score 0):

Have your tried "heroku run bash" https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/one-off-dynos#an-example-one-off-dyno this gives you a bash prompt were you can try to run install command for dbus